# Number in a radius calc trouble python

Tags: python, list, variables, equation

Here is the formula for the radius

```
import math

def calculateDistance( latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ):
DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
alpha = 90 - latTwo
beta  = 90 - latOne

cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
return distance

print calculateDistance(latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo), "metres"
```

Now if i put the values in to the equation like so

```
print calculateDistance(-20.73, 116.75, -21.06, 117.44), "metres"
The answer is 80470.8270982 metres
```

Now here is the trouble. I have variables calculated from a csv folder such that `lat1 = -20 , lon1 = 100 and lat2 = -30 and lon2 = 120` when i run the following code

```
print calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2), "metres"
```

This appears Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Guest\My Documents\SC\Actual work\distance.py", line 104, in <module>
    print calculateDistance(lat0, long0, lat1, long1), "metres"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Guest\My Documents\SC\Actual work\distance.py", line 5, in calculateDistance
    coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Is there anyway to solve it such that when i use my variables that I calculated will produce a numerical value?

Comment: What's your variable scope?

Comment: What do u mean by variable scope?

Comment: Variable scope is when a variable defined in a function is unknown outside a function. It can occasionally cause troubles if a value is changed in one place, but not in another.

Answer (score 2):

The values you are getting from your CSV are of the type `str`. You need to convert them into `float` or `Decimal` for them to work correctly, for example, if you convert them into float, you could do this to your function.

```
def calculateDistance( latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ):
    latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo = [float(x) for x in (latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo)]
    DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
    coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
    alpha = 90 - latTwo
    beta  = 90 - latOne

    cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
    cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
    sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
    sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
    cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

    cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
    cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
    cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
    angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
    distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
    return distance
```

Output Test :

```
>>> calculateDistance('-20', '100', '-30', '120')
2295032.2183717163
```

Or to convert into `Decimal` which offers exact representation of floats.

```
def calculateDistance( latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ):
    from decimal import Decimal
    latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo = [Decimal(x) for x in (latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo)]
    DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
    coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
    alpha = 90 - latTwo
    beta  = 90 - latOne

    cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
    cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
    sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
    sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
    cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

    cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
    cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
    cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
    angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
    distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
    return distance
```

Output Test -

```
>>> calculateDistance('-20', '100', '-30', '120')
2295032.2183717163
```